# Existence of large integer solution for a simple-looking equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is it true that for every $k>0$ Diophantine equation
$$
y^2 + x^2y + z^2x + 1 = 0
$$
has an integer solution $(x,y,z)$ such that $\min\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}\geq k$?

Motivation: this equation arises in the [study](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400714) of the smallest open Diophantine equations. If $H$ is the number obtained after replacing all variables by $2$ and all coefficients by the absolute values, then for the given equation we have $H=4+8+8+1=21$.
For all equations with $H\leq 20$, I can decide the existence of large solutions, and in fact describe all integer solutions in a certain way. I can also do this for all equations of size $H=21$ with three exceptions: the two equations $2x^2+xyz\pm(y^2+1)=0$ discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449559) and this one.

I remark that the equation has infinitely many integer solutions, because, for example, for $x=-145$, the resulting two-variable quadratic equation has infinitely many solutions in integers $(y,z)$. However, this does not answer the question.